# Datatable export set format cell to general jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a script that exports the data from the table to a CSV file. From the CSV file, I have a column for `BIRTHDATE` which format is `MM/DD/YYYY`.

After exporting the data I open it in `MS Excel` but upon checking some of the rows have a different format cell some are General and some are Dates. I can't find which area of my code has a bug. What I wanted to do is make all birthdates format cell to general.

Here's my code using the Datatable jquery plugin

```
dataTable = $("#dataTable").DataTable({

      data: data,   
      columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [0] }],
      columns: [
          {data: 'lastName', title: "LAST_NAME", render(data){
            return data ? data.toUpperCase() : "";
          }},
          {data: 'firstName', title: "FIRST_NAME", render(data){
            return data ? data.toUpperCase() : '';
          }},
          {data: 'middleName', title: "MIDDLE_NAME", render(data){
            return data ? data.toUpperCase() : '';
          }},
          {data: 'suffix', title: "SUFFIX", render(data){
            return data || '';
          }},
          {data: 'birthdate', title: "BIRTHDATE", render(data){
            // return data ? moment(data).format("MM/DD/YYYY") : 'No data available';
            return data ? data : 'No data available';
          }},

        ],
        dom: 'Blrtip',
        buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'csv',
            text: 'CSV',
            title:  "EXPORT - "+$("#selectDate").val(),
            exportOptions: {
                page: 'all'
            },
            footer: true
          },
        
        ],
    })
```

The red ones are formatted to General and the black are formatted to Date
they are both the same dates but I don't know why they have a different result in excel format cells.

[image: here]

[image: here2]

and this is the sample JSON data.

```
[
  {
    "lastName":"USER",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"07/03/1981",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER2",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE2",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"07/19/1990",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER3",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE3",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"03/27/1970",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER4",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE4",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"09/19/1982",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER5",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE5",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"03/30/1996",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER6",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE6",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"06/18/1995",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER7",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE7",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"12/10/1995",
  },
  {
    "lastName":"USER8",
    "firstName":"SAMPLE8",
    "middleName":"",
    "suffix":"",
    "birthdate":"12/07/1994",
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you clarify: (1) A CSV file is a plain-text file - there is no formatting, there are no cells. So, when you write "_some of the rows have a different format cell_", what exactly does that mean? It sounds like you have maybe taken your CSV file and loaded it into Excel. Can you clarify?

Comment: And: (2) How can we recreate the problem you are seeing? For example, can you show us some source data? You describe the data - but showing us an actual sample would be helpful.

Comment: @andrewjames I updated my post. hope you understand it more clearly.. what im doing is after i export my data into CSV i open it to MS Excel thats where i found out that birthdate column have different format cell

Comment: Can you show the source data as text, not as a screenshot? What, for example, is behind those `######` error values?

Comment: Just to add: I don't think this question is directly related to DataTables or jQuery - but rather to CSV data, Excel and default date formatting. I assume the `######` fields contain dates where the values are being interpreted using a `DD/MM/YYYY` format (and the cell is not wide enough to display the full date). Whereas values such as `07/19/1990` are formatted as "General" because they do not fit the `DD/MM/YYYY` format which your Excel file is using by default. This is all guesswork - there isn't enough info in the question to be certain.

Comment: @andrewjames i edited my question and provided the actual data for `######` and sample JSON data

Comment: Thank you - it is clear now. Unfortunately I do not know a clean/simple way to handle this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - what happens if you export directly to Excel, instead of via a CSV file: `extend: 'excel'`